# Can I use LabVIEW to build a spreadsheet where data is saved to different columns according to the date?

Tags: arrays, spreadsheet, labview

I'm trying to make an attendance system using LabVIEW.
For that, I need to save data in different columns according to date.
Is it possible to do so (as shown in the picture?
[image]

Comment: Can you describe what you want to achieve in text, rather than relying on an image link that might break at some point, and so that the question can be more easily indexed by Google?

Comment: @MichaelMacAskill I submitted an edit with the image inlined to take care of that concern. I don't think Kusai has enough reputation points to attach images yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, LabVIEW is a general purpose programming language, so it is definitely possible to do this (as you can write any program you can write in any language in LabVIEW). It is hard to answer your question more precisely without a lot more details. Where is your data coming from? Are you building this spreadsheet all in one go from some data source or are you appending onto a spreadsheet each day as the data comes in? Without this information, it is very hard to be more specific. I see you're new to Stack Overflow... I'll try to guide you to something you can work with, but in the future, try to provide a lot more details... you'll get better answers!

If you build a 2D array of numeric values of your data, then you can use the **Array To Spreadsheet String** function (see image) to translate that data into a string and then write the string to a file. That will work for the purely numeric parts of your spreadsheet. Or you may need to  build up a 2D array of strings if you want those initial columns of names shown in your image. But either way, the **Array To Spreadsheet String** node is the key to easily creating that spreadsheet string. If you look at the Context Help for that function, it defaults to take a 2D array of numerics, but it is polymorphic to take a 2D array of strings directly.

[image]

I hope that helps some. I am assuming you already generally know how to program in LabVIEW (building arrays, writing data to files). If not, you should take an introductory course -- answering the entirety of how LabVIEW works as a language and its basic APIs is well beyond the scope of Stack Overflow answers. :-) Good luck... and welcome to Stack Overflow.